# Does Leaflet provide Geocoding service?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geocoding

I am considering the replacement of Google Maps with Open Street Maps and the Leaflet JS API. Does the Leaflet JS API provide a Geocoding service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Leaflet itself does not provide geocoding services, but you can look at Nominatim for example.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 4):

I found a Leaflet plugin that works great. It's a Bing geocoder which you'll need your own key for  https://github.com/sa3m/leaflet-control-bing-geocoder

Answer (score 2):

I have fallen in love with the [Mapbox Geocoding API](http://mapbox.com/developers/api/#geocoding) -- they do a great job of aggregating a lot of data sources that would be a pain for me to aggregate on my own.  I found it to do a better job of reverse-geocoding than Nominatim.  If I ever needed to build out my own geocoder, Nominatim would be a great place to start, but for most projects it feels to me like overkill.

Comment: From Mapbox docs (unless have granted access to mapbox.places-permanent):
`Supports 1 geocode per request.
Must be displayed on a Mapbox map.` Which is not gonna work if used with leaflet API. Also coverage is quite low, having only 13 countries.